# What does the R in "%sR" do in the String.format()

Tags: java, string, string.format

"%-25s%-15d%n" is the text I used to format a line, but the books answer used "%-25sR%-15d%n", and I could not find out what the R does here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code that you show, `R` is nothing more than a String literal. It is not used by the String Formatter in any format-specific fashion.

```
"%-25sR%-15d%n"
```

The format specifiers in the code above is the `%-25s`, `%-15d` and the `%n`. All other characters are String literals.

Note that per the [java.util.Formatter API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html), there is an `R` format specifier that is used for:

> Time formatted for the 24-hour clock as "%tH:%tM"

But this has nothing to do with your question or posted code.